Identify Grey's anatomy scene about difficulty of planning a surgery
I'm looking for a scene in Grey's Anatomy in which Alex Karev explains to a patient why it's not a bad thing that Meredith Grey will not be able to plan his surgery ahead of time. The patient is a security guard. Karev asks the patient if he would plan a fight in great detail ahead of time, and if the lack of a plan would make him lose the fight. I specifically remember Karev saying, "He [the tumor]'s a punk."
Earlier in the episode Grey had told others (interns?) that the tumor was so challenging she would not even know what to do until she opened up the patient. Based on her tone of voice, she relished the challenge.
There's another episode (later the same season?) in which two surgeons (Derek and Owen?) are competing for (I think) a surgery by providing their plans. The one who argues that planning is futile wins. This is not the scene I'm looking for, although it is related.
